# 'Can't assign to operator' syntax error, Python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

```
import math


def main():  
    loop=eval(input("How many times do you want to run the loop?" ))  
    x=eval(input("What number are you taking the square root of? "))  
    for i in range(loop):  
        x=guess  
        x/2=(guess+(x/guess))/2  
    print(guess)  

main()
```

Comment: `x/2=(guess+(x/guess))/2` - what's this line supposed to do?

Comment: it is a math equation, that uses newtons method, to find square roots

Comment: I'm not asking about its purpose in general. I'm asking about what that line has to do with Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Following line cause a syntax error:

```
x/2=(guess+(x/guess))/2
```

Maybe typo of the following?

```
x = (guess+(x/guess))/2
```